# Equation of a circle with a point on it and two tangents

Tags: analytic-geometry, circles, tangent-line

> A circle goes through $(5,1)$ and is tangent to $x-2y+6=0$ and $x-2y-4=0$. What is the circle's equation?

All I know is that the tangents are parallel, which means I can calculate the radius as half the distance between them: $\sqrt5$. So my equation is
$$(x-p)^2+(y-q)^2=5$$
How can I get the locations of the centre? (I think there are 2 solutions.)

Comment: @Parcly Taxel: nice of you to do the editing. Would you also like to point newcomers to the MathJax tutorial?

Comment: Sry I am new to this site so I didn't know how to format. Btw thank you for your editing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can place an additional constraint on the circle centre $(p,q)$. It has to lie on the line parallel to the two tangents and equidistant from them:
$$p-2q+1=0\quad p=2q-1$$
Then since the circle passes through $(5,1)$:
$$(5-(2q-1))^2+(1-q)^2=5$$
$$25-10(2q-1)+(2q-1)^2+1-2q+q^2=5$$
$$25-20q+10+4q^2-4q+1+1-2q+q^2=5$$
$$5q^2-26q+32=0$$
$$(q-2)(5q-16)=0$$
$$q=2\text{ or }\frac{16}5$$
Therefore the two possible centres are $(3,2)$ and $\left(\frac{27}5,\frac{16}5\right)$, leading to the circle equations
$$(x-3)^2+(y-2)^2=5$$
$$\left(x-\frac{27}5\right)^2+\left(y-\frac{16}5\right)^2=5$$

Comment: I believe the radius is incorrect.

Comment: @mrnovice Go plot the equations in Desmos. The radius you give is too big.

Comment: Seems I made an error

Comment: Yes Parcly your equations are correct.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel Although thanks for that desmos link, it will be very useful for me in the future :)

Comment: +1 for using analysis to reduce the maybe-necessary computation.

Answer (score 0):

As the radius $=$ the perpendicular distance of a tangent from the center.

If $(h,k)$ is the center, radius $r=\dfrac{|h-2k+6|}{\sqrt{1^2+2^2}}=\dfrac{|h-2k-4|}{\sqrt{1^2+2^2}}$

Squaring we get, $$(h-2k+6)^2=(h-2k-4)^2\iff h=2k-1$$

$r=\dfrac{|-1+6|}{\sqrt{1^2+2^2}}=\sqrt5$

Finally $$(\sqrt5)^2=(h-5)^2+(k-1)^2=(2k-1-5)^2+(k-1)^2$$

$k=?$